# DockedCell in the Wolfram Player?

Tags: wolfram-player

Is it possible to put a docked cell in a notebook that you can view using the wolfram player on IOS?  This webpage ( https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpADockedCell.html ) indicates it’s possible on mobile.  But are they referring only to the wolfram cloud app on mobile?

Also, it seems like wolfram is investing a lot into the wolfram cloud app which is great, although I’ve had nothing but issues trying to use it so far.  In any case, are they planning to get rid of the wolfram player at some point?  It seems like this might be the case.  I hope not.  The player is more robust, faster and fully interactive as it runs a native version of Mathematica which is far superior for my needs.  If it’s going by the wayside, I suppose I’ll stop investing my time into it.

Comment: Regarding your second question - I don't think anyone here is going to have any insight for you on that, since we're overwhelmingly a group of unaffiliated volunteers. There are a few WRI employees here but not that many. You might have better luck asking in the Wolfram Community forums.